# Проблема индексации мультиязычной страницы

Tags: i18n, crawling

Я разрабатываю вебсайт и я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: гугл не правильно индексирует мою страницу.

На моем сайте стоит детектор языка пользователя. Для этого я использую специальную js-библиотеку - [i19next + i18n-browser-languageDetector](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector). Чтобы не портить "красоту сайта" различными субдоменами, окончаниями доменов, путями (`example.com/ru/...`), я решил просто использовать вид `example.com` для всех страниц, а сайт будет подбирать язык в зависимости от языка браузера. Когда юзер хочет сменить язык и чтобы страница запомнила - мною просто используется функция по смене языка и запись этого в cookie-файл.

Недавно запустил индексацию страницы от google и он проиндексировал страницу на английском, однако это не тот язык, который я хотел бы видеть в поисковике. Я решил использовать в html мета-тег `<link rel="alternate" href={window.location.href} hrefLang="x-default"/>`, но это пока не дало результатов.

Вопрос: как правильно проиндексировать одну и ту же страницу на разных языках, как это делает facebook? В отличии от выбранного языка в гугле, будут показываться одна и та же ссылка на facebook, но на разных языках